# How to convert Dynamodb stream DynamoDBEvent new image or old image to my own concrete object type T without manual mapping?

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a lambda function that is triggered from a DynamoDB stream event. The object it accepts is a `DynamoDBEvent` from the `Amazon.Lambda.DynamoDBEvents` Nuget package.

```
public async Task FunctionHandler(DynamoDBEvent event, ILambdaContext context)
{
    foreach (var record in event.Records)
    {
        var newImage = event.Dynamodb.NewImage; // Or "OldImage" property
        var myObject = new MyObject();

        myObject.ItemId = newImage["ItemId"].N;
        myObject.IdList = newImage["IdList"].NS;
        myObject.CustomerName = newImage["CustomerName"].S;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to easily convert this event to my own class, like the one below, eg:

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public List<int> IdList { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Without having to create my own mapper that manipulates the DynamoDBEvent object for each individual property of every type?

The `AttributeValue` class contains lots of different properties, one for each type the DynamoDb supports and my object may become complex with nested properties in the future.

The Document model from the DynamodDB library seems to be able to do it already...

`NewImage` and `OldImage` is of type `Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Amazon.Lambda.DynamoDBEvents` Nuget package that contains the definitions for `DynamoDBEvent` already has a dependency on the package `AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2` which already contains the code for the [.NET DynamoDB Document Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKMidLevel.html) to convert from a `Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>` to another object.

We can write a helper method that utilises `FromAttributeMap` and `FromDocument` to convert it:

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model;

public class DynamoDbStreamToObject
{
    private static readonly AmazonDynamoDBConfig ClientConfig = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1 };
    private static readonly DynamoDBContext DynamoDbContext = new DynamoDbContext(newAmazonDynamoDBClient(ClientConfig));

    public static T Convert<T>(Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> dynamoDbImage) 
    {
        var dynamoDocument = Document.FromAttributeMap(dynamoDbImage);
        return DynamoDbContext.FromDocument<T>(dynamoDocument);
    }
}
```

First it converts `Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>` to an Amazon DynamoDB `Document` and from that to your object.

Your function handler can now be simplified by using this helper method to the following:

```
public async Task FunctionHandler(DynamoDBEvent event, ILambdaContext context)
{
    foreach (var record in input.Records)
    {
        var newImage = event.Dynamodb.NewImage; // Or "OldImage" property
        var myObject = DynamoDbStreamToObject.Convert<MyObject>(newImage);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this requires a kind've redundant DynamoDBContext (Redundant because it's not connecting to DynamoDB itself), but it seems to work.

Comment: Luke, is there a way to ignore properties form the DynamoDB record that are not part of the object?  I'm getting System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch when I try this solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Just in case someone runs into the same issue, I was using _dynameDbContext.FromDocument instead of Document.FromAttribubeMap and that was the issue.  Once changed to Luke's example, it worked like a charm.

Comment: This is no longer working because of the recent changes in the libraries. https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/1657

Answer (score 0):

With the latest update, the above code doesn't work anymore. It breaks the `FromAttributeMap()` . See the details here - https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/1657. The work around is to, convert to json, then from json create the document back.

```
private T GetObject<T>(Dictionary<string, DynamoDBEvent.AttributeValue> image)
{
    var document =  Document.FromJson(image.ToJson());
    return DynamoDbContext.FromDocument<T>(document);
}
```